# jQuery with Webpack 2

Tags: jquery, webpack-2

My webpack.config.js looks as below :

```js
var debug = process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production";
var webpack = require('webpack');
var path = require('path');
var node_dir = __dirname + '/node_modules';
const autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer');
const ProvidePlugin = require('webpack/lib/ProvidePlugin');

module.exports = {
  context: path.join(__dirname, "src"),
  devtool: debug ? "inline-sourcemap" : null,
  entry: ['tether',
    'font-awesome-loader',"bootstrap-loader","./js/client.js"],
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.styl'],
    alias: {
      'jquery': node_dir + '/jquery/src/jquery.js',
    }
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        query: {
          presets: ['react', 'es2015', 'stage-0'],
          plugins: ['react-html-attrs', 'transform-decorators-legacy', 'transform-class-properties'],
        }
      },
      { test: /\.css$/, use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'postcss-loader'] },
      { test: /\.scss$/, use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'postcss-loader', 'sass-loader'] },
      {
        test: /\.woff2?(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/,
        use: 'url-loader?limit=10000',
      },
      {
        test: /\.(ttf|eot|svg)(\?[\s\S]+)?$/,
        use: 'file-loader',
      },
      {
      test: /\.styl$/,
      use: [
        'style-loader',
        'css-loader',
        {
          loader: 'stylus-loader',
          /*options: {
            use: [stylus_plugin()],
          },*/
        },
      ],
    },
      // Use one of these to serve jQuery for Bootstrap scripts:

      // Bootstrap 4
      { test: /bootstrap\/dist\//, use: 'imports-loader?jQuery=jquery' },
    ]
  },
  output: {
    path: __dirname + "/dist/",
    filename: "client.min.js"
  },
  plugins:  [
    //new webpack.optimize.DedupePlugin(),
    //new webpack.optimize.OccurenceOrderPlugin(),
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({ mangle: false, sourcemap: false }),
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      $: "jquery",
      jQuery: "jquery",
      "window.jQuery": "jquery",
      Tether: "tether",
      "window.Tether": "tether",
      Alert: "exports-loader?Alert!bootstrap/js/dist/alert",
      Button: "exports-loader?Button!bootstrap/js/dist/button",
      Carousel: "exports-loader?Carousel!bootstrap/js/dist/carousel",
      Collapse: "exports-loader?Collapse!bootstrap/js/dist/collapse",
      Dropdown: "exports-loader?Dropdown!bootstrap/js/dist/dropdown",
      Modal: "exports-loader?Modal!bootstrap/js/dist/modal",
      Popover: "exports-loader?Popover!bootstrap/js/dist/popover",
      Scrollspy: "exports-loader?Scrollspy!bootstrap/js/dist/scrollspy",
      Tab: "exports-loader?Tab!bootstrap/js/dist/tab",
      Tooltip: "exports-loader?Tooltip!bootstrap/js/dist/tooltip",
      Util: "exports-loader?Util!bootstrap/js/dist/util",
    }),
    new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({
      postcss: [autoprefixer],
    })
  ],
};
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>React, Babel, Webpack 2</title>
  </head>
  <body class="container">
    <div id="app"></div>
    <script src="jquery.timeago.js"></script>
    <script src="client.min.js"></script>
    
  </body>
</html>
```

But when I try to use jQuery.timeago() function I am getting below error.

[image]

I was following React By Example book. When I type window.jQuery I am getting some wierd numbers appearing after jQuery. But when I just type jQuery I am getting undefined. As bootstrap 4 and $.ajax() is working I am sure that jQuery is included but not sure why jQuery shows undifined.

Can anybody explain how jQuery is being included and what am I doing wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add plugin to plugin section of your `webpack` config like this:

```js
var webpack = require('webpack')
...

plugins: [
  new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
    $: 'jquery',
    jQuery: 'jquery',
  })
]
```

EDIT:

You have cyclic dependency:

```
timeago: jquery
client: timeago jquery
```

but `jquery` and `client` is same bundle. Try to switch of include js bundles in html like this:

```html
<script src="client.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.timeago.js"></script>
```

instead of:

```html
<script src="jquery.timeago.js"></script>
<script src="client.min.js"></script>
```

If that does not help or you have another errors you need to extract jquery to separated bundle and include it before `timeago`. Another way is to include `jquery` like old school for example from cdn and make webpack know that like this:

```js
externals: {
  jquery: 'jQuery'
}
```

To extract jquery to separated bundle and make it visible for timeago use include sequence like this:

```html
<script src="common.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.timeago.js"></script>
<script src="client.min.js"></script>
```

And use webpack common chunk plugin like this:

```js
entry: {
  common: ["jquery"],
  ...
},
plugins: [
  new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
    name: "common",
    filename: "common.js",
    minChunks: Infinity,
  })
],
```

Comment: HI. If you see my webpack.config.js file I have already done that. But still I am getting undefined.

Comment: I extends an answer. Hope you will have success.

Comment: Hi. I changed the order of script tags. Did not work. Can you explain this "you need to extract js to separated bundle and include it before timeago". I am new to webpack.

Comment: I explane some example. I hope you will succeed.